# MS Access 2010 database

Tags: database, ms-access

I am not sure if this the proper forum for my kind of question but since you all guys are programmers perhaps you know a bit of everything. :)

So what I want to do is to create in `MS Access` a simple contact database (for my clients). BUT I want for each of my contacts (AKA records) to be able to add info assigned to dates (something like subform-record I guess) one info (note) assigned to one date for each record/client

```
Example: 
Record 1: Bill Smith. 
Date 17/02/2012 note: "I got 30$"
Date 18/05/2012 note: "I got 30$"

Record 2: Spencer Williams. 
Date 17/02/2012 note: "I got 30$"
Date 18/05/2012 note: "I got 30$"
Date 19/05/2012 note: "I got 30$"
and so on...
```

notice that different records will give me info in the same dates sometimes.

In conclusion I wanna make a contact database for my clients but since I am having regular dates with them I want to take notes for each client  : "what date" , "how much he gave me".

Answer (score 1):

in case you are new comer in ms access world, I recommended to look at ready to use template. That can be downloaded from Microsoft site. For example : [microsoft templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?qu=access&av=zac)

in this et of template there is contact database